# Building POCO on OSX gives warning during linking

Tags: macos, poco-libraries

Hi I have built Poco on OSX 10.11 using the following commands:

```
./configure --static --no-tests --no-samples --omit=Data/ODBC,Data/MySQL,Data/MongoDB --include-path=$OPENSSL_INCLUDE_PATH
make -j2
```

My deployment target in XCODE is set to 10.10 and hence when I run the project I get several warnings of type:
`ld: warning: object file (libPocoNetSSL.a(PrivateKeyFactory.o) was built for newer OSX version (10.11) than being linked (10.10)`

How can I build POCO for 10.10, Is there any custom flag or directive that can be used?

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `-mmacosx-version-min=10.10` to [Darwin-clang](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/build/config/Darwin-clang#L55).